# Type annotations for a tuple of arguments and the associated function

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

In one of my programs I made a list of tuples containing a function on one side and on the other a tuple with the arguments I want to send to it by unpacking it.
Like that :

```
def func1(idx: int, enable: bool) -> None:
    # Do thing
    pass

def func2(enable: bool) -> None:
    # Do thing
    pass

my_tuple_list = []

my_tuple_list.append((func1, (2, True))) # Tuple[Callable[[int, bool], None], Tuple[int, bool]]
my_tuple_list.append((func2, (False,))) # Tuple[Callable[[bool], None], Tuple[bool]]

for func, args in my_tuple_list:
    func(*args)
```

But since functions take different types of arguments, I would just like to tell MyPy that the types in the Tuple with args must be identical to what the function expects.
Example of what I have currently :

```
TupleFunc1: TypeAlias = Tuple[Callable[[bool], None], Tuple[bool]]
TupleFunc2: TypeAlias = Tuple[Callable[[int, bool], None], Tuple[int, bool]]
TupleFunc3: TypeAlias = Tuple[Callable[[str], None], Tuple[str]]
```

And I would like something like:

```
TupleFunc: TypeAlias = Tuple[Callable[[T], None], Tuple[T]]
```

At first I wanted to start with Unions, but I told myself that if one day I add functions, it would quickly become complicated to maintain.

I also try ParamSpec and TypeVar, but I failed to do a thing without MyPy errors.

Ideas on how I might manage this ?

Comment: Please add a simple concrete example of a function that you want to annotate.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Like that is better?

Comment: Yes. So, you would like a _generic_ type to annotate a 2-tuple consisting of a callable and its arguments. Do I understand you correctly? Also, from your example I gather that you are only interested in the second element in the tuple being _positional_ arguments, never keyword arguments for the function, correct?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Yes, you understand correctly what I mean.
And yes, the second element of the tuple will always be positional arguments.

Comment: This is harder than I thought. One of the challenges here is that even something that should be normal use of a generic `Callable[P, T]` inside a tuple leads to an incorrect `mypy` error. (See [issue here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11855).) So I am not sure this is possible with the tools currently available. I'll try some more stuff, but I am not optimistic.

Comment: You cannot yet with `mypy`. It requires [pep646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) to define `_TT = TypeVarTuple('_TT'); def f(func: Callable[[*_TT], _R], args: Iterable[tuple[*TT]])`

Comment: @SUTerliakov Nice! I wasn't aware of this PEP. Looking forward to variadic generics in the future.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thank you for your answer!
So I'm going to leave the typing of my program where it is, and hope that it won't take too long for MyPy to update on that!

Comment: Since this question is still alive, I'd suggest just changing your API to take 0-ary callable. Any function that wants arguments can then be expressed as `functools.partial(n_ary_func, arg1=..., ...)`, the typing is simply `Callable[[], Any]`, and your options are not limited to positional args any more.